# proof for inequality

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

Hi I am trying to understand a step of a proof, why is it true that

$$\left [ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|t{f(t)}{f'^*(t)}|\,dt\right]^2\ge\left [ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{t}{2}[{f'(t)}f^*(t)+{f'^*(t)}f(t)]\,dt\right]^2?$$

**EDIT**: $f\in\mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$, $f^*$ is just the complex conjugate of $f$

Comment: What is $f^{\ast}$ and your $f$ belongs to which functions space ?

Comment: @DivyangBhimani : $f\in\mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$, $f^*$ is just the complex conjugate of $f$

Comment: If $f\in L^2$ what is then $f^\prime$? The derivative need not exist, not even in the weak sense.

Comment: How do you know the left side is real?

Comment: @T.A.E.: I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your edit, it's obvious because $|f(t)^{\star}f'(t)|=|f(t)f'(t)^{\star}|$ and 
$$
\begin{align}
     \left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{t}{2}\left[f(t)f'(t)^{\star}+f(t)^{\star}f'(t)\right]dt\right| & \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|t|}{2}(|f(t)f'(t)^{\star}|+|f(t)^{\star}f'(t)|)dt \\
    & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|tf(t)f'(t)^{\star}|dt.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: the inequality is true for your answer because of triangle inequality?

Comment: @freak_warrior: Yes and $|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}gdt| \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g|dt$